# How to change mongo.conf to set journaling

Tags: mongodb, openshift, journaling

I'm looking to change '/etc/mongo.conf' to set journaling `smallfiles=true`, but I don't have write permission.

Is there a right way to to it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right file to change:
vi mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf

and journaling option is already set:

```
# Specific configuration for openshift cartridge
smallfiles = true
quiet = true
```